# useEffect runs twice for user create redirect flow

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito

I am creating a small app that uses AWS Authentication (it provides convenient handling of social and non-social logins). On the redirect flow from AWS, I subscribe to logged-in event inside useEffect and create user via POST to my server.

Unfortunately, useEffect runs twice (I put a log there to confirm). Another SO post suggested that useEffect should be pure and <React.StrictMode> is causing this. What would be the suggested flow to create the account here?

My code so far:

```
export default function LoginRedirect() {
    const _userService = new UserService();
    const navigator = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("activating useEffect in LoginRedirect");

        const getUserAndProcess = async (eventCancelToken: () => void) => {
            try {
                console.log("processing user...");
                const currentUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() as CognitoUser
                if(currentUser != null) eventCancelToken() //stop listening to any more auth events
                else return;

                const userSession = currentUser.getSignInUserSession();
                const idToken = userSession?.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
                const accessToken = userSession?.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
                const refreshToken = userSession?.getRefreshToken().getToken();

                if(idToken === undefined || accessToken === undefined || refreshToken === undefined) {
                    throw new Error("idToken, accessToken, or refreshToken is undefined");
                }

                const processUserResult = await _userService.processUser(
                    {
                        IdToken: idToken
                    } as ProcessUser
                );

                console.log(currentUser);
                console.log(processUserResult);

                navigator("/");

            } catch(error) {
                console.warn(error);
            }
        };

        const authListenerCancelToken = Hub.listen("auth", ({ payload: { event, data }}) => {
            switch (event) {
                case 'signIn':
                    console.log('Sign in happened!', data);
                    getUserAndProcess(authListenerCancelToken)
                        .catch(console.error);
                    break;
                case 'cognitoHostedUI':
                    console.log('Sign in happened via cognito hosted UI!', data);
                    break;
                case "signOut":
                    break;
                case 'signIn_failure':
                case 'cognitoHostedUI_failure':
                    console.log('Sign in failure', data);
                    break;
            }
        });

        getUserAndProcess(authListenerCancelToken).catch(console.error);
    });


  return (
      <div className="h-screen w-full grid place-items-center">
          <div className="grid place-items-center">
              <h1 className="text-lg my-3">Logging you in...</h1>
              <div className="loading loading-ring loading-lg justify-self-center"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with the second parameter of `useEffect` as a blank array, so it will get called once the page has loaded:

```
useEffect(() => {
}, []);
```

Comment: already tried this. I think it is due to this reason (link provided), but I am looking for ideas how to re-arrange this logic if useEffect is a bad place for this.

https://beta-reactjs-org-git-effects-fbopensource.vercel.app/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#how-to-handle-the-effect-firing-twice-in-development

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
export default function LoginRedirect() {
    const _userService = new UserService();
    const navigator = useNavigate();
const getUserAndProcess = async (eventCancelToken: () => void) => {
            try {
                console.log("processing user...");
                const currentUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() as CognitoUser
                if(currentUser != null) eventCancelToken() //stop listening to any more auth events
                else return;

                const userSession = currentUser.getSignInUserSession();
                const idToken = userSession?.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
                const accessToken = userSession?.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
                const refreshToken = userSession?.getRefreshToken().getToken();

                if(idToken === undefined || accessToken === undefined || refreshToken === undefined) {
                    throw new Error("idToken, accessToken, or refreshToken is undefined");
                }

                const processUserResult = await _userService.processUser(
                    {
                        IdToken: idToken
                    } as ProcessUser
                );

                console.log(currentUser);
                console.log(processUserResult);

                navigator("/");

            } catch(error) {
                console.warn(error);
            }
        };



let ignore;


    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("activating useEffect in LoginRedirect");
       if(ignore){
         return;
        }:
        
        // maybe unMount this listener 
        const authListenerCancelToken = Hub.listen("auth", ({ payload: { event, data }}) => {
            switch (event) {
                case 'signIn':
                    console.log('Sign in happened!', data);
                    getUserAndProcess(authListenerCancelToken)
                        .catch(console.error);
                    break;
                case 'cognitoHostedUI':
                    console.log('Sign in happened via cognito hosted UI!', data);
                    break;
                case "signOut":
                    break;
                case 'signIn_failure':
                case 'cognitoHostedUI_failure':
                    console.log('Sign in failure', data);
                    break;
            }
        });
// maybe get .then() for not lauch again if 
        getUserAndProcess(authListenerCancelToken).catch(console.error);

return () => {
ignore= true;
authListenerCancelToken() 
// for unmount listener when useEffect is Unmounted
}

    }, []);


  return (
      <div className="h-screen w-full grid place-items-center">
          <div className="grid place-items-center">
              <h1 className="text-lg my-3">Logging you in...</h1>
              <div className="loading loading-ring loading-lg justify-self-center"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Try this, but I don't understand why it's not a button that simply engages the function?

Otherwise, I've just extracted the useEffect logic, added an empty dependency array and added a variable to know whether or not the useEffect has already been called.

[Linster unmount function in docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/auth/auth-events/)

When using useEffect, think about the dependency table and ask yourself whether anything needs to be removed after disassembly (listener in particular).

Comment: It cannot be a button because this is a redirect page a social provider redirects to (AWS in this example)

Comment: StrictMode disassembles and reassembles useEffect a second time; this is normal behavior and is not present in production. It's important to understand that useEffect uses side effects and can quickly turn into a problem, so make sure that launching it several times doesn't affect the data and doesn't break anything; in your case, I don't think it's a problem to launch this function twice, but it's mainly the listener that needs to be disassembled in the useEffect return function.

Comment: It depends on the behavior you want, I don't know enough about the AWS authentication flow to tell you more, but there are two important things: when a listener is mounted here `authListenerCancelToken` use a return function in useEffect to unmount it here `authListenerCancelToken() ` must be called afterwards.